# How can I return two lists that are DISTINCT?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

How can I return two lists that are `DISTINCT`? I use `UNWIND` clause to do that with one, but the problem arises when I want to have two independent lists with `DISTINCT` elements.

Here is my code:

```
WITH [1,1,1,2,2,3]AS list, [2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,1]as list2
UNWIND listAS listElement
UNWIND list2AS listElement2
WITHDISTINCT listElement, listElement2
RETURN collect(listElement)AS distinctElements, collect(listElement2)AS distinctElements2;
```

I want to get two lists with DISTINCT elements, and now I get duplicates.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine both lists in one list and then check if the elements of one list are in that combo list. If they are, they are from the first list, if not, they are from the second one.

On top of that, you can unwind lists one by one:

```
WITH [1,1,1,2,2,3] AS list, [2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,1] AS list2
UNWIND list AS listElement
WITH DISTINCT listElement, list2
WITH collect(listElement) as list, list2
UNWIND list2 as listElement
WITH DISTINCT listElement, list
RETURN list, collect(listElement) AS list2;
```